# Python webapp2 user authentication with MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, webapp2, authentication

I have a MySQL database, and want to have user accounting in my webpage. Honestly I don't want to write it from scratch. I know webapp2 have authentication but i don't know how to use it with MySQL database. Does anyone have any idea or have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/) article explains in detail how to deal with user authentication using the webapp2_extras.auth module. It involves using the Datastore for user data. You’ll have to migrate your existing user base from MySQL db, but it’ll be a better choice for your use case than Cloud SQL.